# How to make the currency for an economy bot?

Tags: c#, bots, discord

I am trying to make an economy bot for discord using C#. I am confused about how I am going to do it. I might have to use databases but in that case how do I make it so it makes a new line for every user that has used the command. Any help would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a database. If this is your first time using databases, I highly recommened [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). You should also see video tutorials such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayp3tHEkRc0) one.

Once you have familiarised yourself with a SQLite databases then you will be able to answer your own question extremely easily. It is not difficult and requires some very simple logic. Attempt it yourself first and if you are still stuck reply to this answer.

Consider viewing this [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) resource when you are comfortable with the basics.